# specs2 -- Could not create an instance

Tags: scala, specs2

```
testOnly play.api.weibo.StatusesShowBatchSpec
[error] Could not create an instance of play.api.weibo.StatusesShowBatchSpec
[error]   caused by java.lang.Exception: Could not instantiate class play.api.weibo.StatusesShowBatchSpec: null
[error]   org.specs2.reflect.Classes$class.tryToCreateObjectEither(Classes.scala:93)
[error]   org.specs2.reflect.Classes$.tryToCreateObjectEither(Classes.scala:211)
[error]   org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure$$anonfun$createSpecificationEither$2.apply(BaseSpecification.scala:119)
[error]   org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure$$anonfun$createSpecificationEither$2.apply(BaseSpecification.scala:119)
...
```

The spec

```
package play.api.weibo

import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.specs2.runner.JUnitRunner

class StatusesShowBatchSpec extends ApiSpec {

  "'statuses show batch' api" should {
    "read statuses" in {
      val api = StatusesShowBatch(
        accessToken = testAdvancedToken,
        ids = "3677163356078857")
      val res = awaitApi(api)
      res.statuses must have size (1)
    }
```

}
}

See full code here https://github.com/jilen/play-weibo/tree/spec2_error

Full stacktrace
https://gist.github.com/jilen/9050548

Comment: I'm getting match error instead: ` scala.MatchError: Left(play.api.weibo.WeiboApiError: Weibo api error: source paramter(appkey) is missing, code: 10006: request: /2/statuses/show_batch.json) (of class scala.util.Left)`. Are you sure you didn't already fix it?

Comment: Thanks, I have switched to scalatest, then found the problem,seems,exception eat by spec2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `ApiSpec` class you have a few variables which might be null at instantiation time:

```
val cfg = ConfigFactory.load("http.conf")
val testToken = cfg.getString("token.normal")
val testAdvancedToken = cfg.getString("token.advanced")

implicit val http = new SprayHttp {
  val config = new SprayHttpConfig {
    val system = ActorSystem("test")
    val gzipEnable = true
  }
  val context = config.system.dispatcher
}
```

You can turn those vals into lazy vals to avoid this situation:

```
lazy val cfg = ConfigFactory.load("http.conf")
lazy val testToken = cfg.getString("token.normal")
lazy val testAdvancedToken = cfg.getString("token.advanced")

implicit lazy val http = new SprayHttp {
  lazy val config = new SprayHttpConfig {
    val system = ActorSystem("test")
    val gzipEnable = true
  }
  val context = config.system.dispatcher
}
```

Comment: the specs2 seems lose some stacktrace

Comment: There is indeed some filtering going on by default. You can get the full stack trace by using `test-only *StatusesShowBatchSpec* -- fullstacktrace`.

Comment: https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/pull/236  The stack trace is not fully Then I submit this.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting a very similar error using specs2 version [2.3.10 on Scala 2.10](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.specs2/specs2_2.10/2.3.10). Upgrading to [2.3.13](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.specs2/specs2_2.10/2.3.13) makes the error messages much more informative and provides an extra stacktrace to the root cause. This newer version was released very recently (8 days before this post!), so hopefully you're able to accommodate an update...

Some of my issues ended up being related the `val` vs. `lazy val` problem like in the accepted answer; however, I'm now able to pinpoint the exact line that these errors are occurring on in addition to debugging other initialization problems as well.

Comment: Ahaaa. Looks like it was migrated into an actual release then. Thanks for the fix!